# Hiding tabs/fields based on Roles

Tags: acumatica

Is anyone faced an issue like, after hiding tab on any screen, still able to see that tab text (no fields in it) after clicking on Cancel(Esc) button?

Tab will hide when you refresh the page but I observed this only after clicking on Cancel(Esc) button.

Build & Version: 2017R2 17.200.0401

Comment: How are you hiding the tab?

Comment: Hi Samvel, am selecting a field (Item Class in Stock Items screen) in Access Rights by Screen and there am changing the access rights to Revoked for some roles.

Comment: Actually, I was unable to hide the entire tab at once, so I selected each and every field and changed the status

Comment: Have a look at Sergey's blog for instructions on how to hide tab : http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/05/hiding-tab-from-user-interface.html

Comment: Thank you, Simon, that is useful but really not fulfills my requirement, because I think Sergey's post is hiding based on Visible Expression, but how can I do same for particular roles in the .aspx page

Comment: The other option is to hide every controls in the tab item then the tab will disappear.

Comment: Hello HB_ACUMATICA, I did in the same way you suggested and i was able to hide the tab, but when I press the Cancel(ESC) button again am able to see only the tab but no controls in it.

Answer (score 0):

This function below will return true if the logged in user is a member of the passed role.
Then you can use the PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible method.

```
  public static bool IsUserAMemberOf(string roleName, PXGraph graph)
        {
            var myUserName = graph.Accessinfo.UserName;

            UsersInRoles assigned = PXSelect<UsersInRoles,
                Where<UsersInRoles.username, Equal<Required<Users.username>>, And<UsersInRoles.rolename, Equal<Required<UsersInRoles.rolename>>>>>
                .Select(graph, myUserName, roleName);

            if (assigned == null)
                return false;

            return true;

        }
```